# The ContextMenu and the sublevels

Tags: python, pyqt5, contextmenu, levels

I am able to create a ContextMenu with a level and a first sublevel. I was trying to add more sublevels but I can't. I searched the Internet for a long time to find some examples, but nothing. In my example, how should I modify the code to add the 'Brenda' option in the second sublevel? Please look at the picture. Thanks.

[image: ContextMenu Image]

```
def contextMenuEvent(self,event):

    menu = QMenu(self)

    Option1 = menu.addAction("Paul")

    Option2 = QMenu("Richard")
    Option2_1 = Option2.addAction("Frida")
    Option2_2 = Option2.addAction("Susan")
    menu.addMenu(Option2)

    Option3 = menu.addAction("Thomas")

    action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
    if action == Option1:
        print("Paul")
    elif action == Option2_1:
        print("Frida")
    elif action == Option2_2:
        print("Susan")
    elif action == Option3:
        print("Thomas")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this be how to achieve a third menu layer?

```
def contextMenuEvent(self,event):

    menu = QMenu(self)

    Option1 = menu.addAction("Paul")

    Option2 = QMenu("Richard")
    Option2_1 = Option2.addAction("Frida")
    Option2_2 = QMenu("Susan") # define a new menu, not an action
    Option2_2_1 = Option2_2.addAction("Brenda") # add sub menu item
    Option2.addMenu(Option2_2) # add menu to Option2 menu
    menu.addMenu(Option2)

    Option3 = menu.addAction("Thomas")

    action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
    if action == Option1:
        print("Paul")
    elif action == Option2_1:
        print("Frida")
    elif action == Option2_2:
        print("Susan")
    elif action == Option3:
        print("Thomas")
```